# a generic error occurred in gdi+ in RDLC Report + Export Report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have ASP.Net Application having RDLC Report..

Whenever i try to export Report in PDF format i gets following error :

```
a generic error occurred in gdi+ in RDLC Report +
```

what is the problem? and how can i solve this problem?